# Coordinates with no decimals when opening GeoJSON in QGIS

Tags: geojson, coordinates, qgis-2, import

When I open the following GeoJSON file in QGIS 2.18 (drag and drop), all point coordinates lost their decimals going, for example, from `(-9.350659,44.32844)` to `(9,44)`.

The same file is correctly shown by online GeoJSON validators.

```
<code>
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -9.350659,
                    41.32844
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "name": "",
                "description": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -9.31515,
                    41.324892
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "name": "",
                "description": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -9.345253,
                    41.347425
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "name": "",
                "description": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -9.373701,
                    41.332987
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "name": "",
                "description": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -9.312632,
                    41.3205906
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "name": "",
                "description": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
</code>
```

Comment: Which QGIS are you using and how do you import the file? I don't have this issue with QGIS 2.18.2

Comment: QGIS 2.18.16

I drag and drop the file (points.geojson) to QGIS , points appear all in the same position (-9,41) since all decimals are trunked. 

Then I open the layer attribute table and add a virtual field to see coordinates ($x and $y) , only integers appear.

Comment: Did you select "Decimal number (real)" as field type when creating the new virtual field?

Comment: Yes. 

Now I have just seen an error in logs , see question edit. I think problem is that geojson coordinates are geografic and qgis project use projected coordinates

Comment: Error is not related , it's from previous operation. I deleted it.

Comment: There is/was a bug report https://issues.qgis.org/issues/11587 regarding your issue, however it should already be fixed when you use QGIS 2.18 (with GDAL 2.0+). Can you please check the GDAL version your QGIS installation uses in Help > About. And which language have you set in QGIS?

Comment: You did the trick. I was using QGIS 2.18 with GDAL 1.x. After updating to version 2.0+ problem was solved, thank you. You can write it as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue this morning.

I am working with QGIS2.8.6 compiled against GDAL1.11.3 on Ubuntu16.04.

I fixed the issue by changing my locale parameters to C.UTF-8 (my locale parameters were previously fr_FR.utf8).

To do so I edited my `/etc/default/locale` file.
It's all explained here: https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Configure_Locales_in_Ubuntu.

Pin: wouldn't it be nice if you could describe how you fixed your issue in an other answer? I wasn't sure how to update my gdal version for QGIS. Some hint would have been nice. Luckily I wanted to changed my langage parameters to american english for several reasons, but others might want to keep their langage parameters and wouldn't be able to use my fix.